SharepointOnline CSOM code issue - Document set shared metadata not applied to documents in set
We are having issues with custom metadata shared columns replicating to the underlying documents within the documentset.
Issue 1: We created a new documentset in SharePoint using CSOM code.
Some custom metadata columns are set as shared for this documentset. When we update the custom metadata for the documentset, it is not applying to the child documents, if the collection has more than 9 documents. If the documentset has less than 9 documents, it replicates fine.
Issue 2: We created a documentset in SharePoint using CSOM code - CopyFolder (MoveCopyUtil.CopyFolder). Some custom metadata columns are set as shared for this documentset, similar to the above scenario. None documents shared metadata is updated, when the metadata in the parent documentset got updated.
If we go to SharePoint directly and update the metadata of the parent documentset and then try again with CSOM code, its started working. It needs a manual trigger in SharePoint to work. We might have the issue1 here as well, if it gets started working.
Library used: Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM version 16.1.23109.12000
